# Exception handling in Laravel 4 - Problems understanding flow

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have problems understanding how Laravel handles exceptions. 
I registered Exception handlers in global.php like this:

```
use MyNamespace\Custom\Exceptions\NotAllowedException; 
App::error(function(NotAllowedException $exception, $code) 
{
  die("MyNamespace\Custom\Exceptions\NotAllowedException catched"); 
});

App::error(function(\Exception $exception)
{
    echo "general exception thrown<br/>"; 

});
```

In a controller action I now throw a NotAllowedException. The strange part however is, that first Exception is catched and NotFoundException afterwards.

The output thus is:

```
general exception thrown 
MyNamespace\Custom\Exceptions\NotAllowedException catched
```

I thought that exception handlers stack and therefore only NotAllowedException is being handled. But I'm wrong. Do I misunderstand the concepts of error handling in Laravel or is this unexpected behaviour?

Another thing: I am not able to set http response header to 401. There are other threads on SO regarding this problem but without a solution so far. If anyone knows something about that either, I would appreciate.

Thank you for you time and every response! 
Cheers

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Exception handling can be seen as a reversed waterfall. The last handler that is defined, is checked first. Take this example:

```
// Custom Exception
class CustomException extends Exception {}

// Error handler in global.php
App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code)
{
    echo 'Debug: Exception<br/>';
});

App::error(function(CustomException $exception, $code)
{
    echo 'Debug: CustomException<br/>';
});

// Exception in routes.php (or any other place)
throw new CustomException();
```

Both types match the Exception type, so this outputs:
Debug: CustomException
Debug: Exception

However, if you return something from within your handler, ONLY the first matching handler is triggered. To return a JSON response with a HTTP 401 response code, do something like:

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code)
{
    return Response::json(array(
        'error' => 'Something went wrong (Exception)'
    ), 500);
});

App::error(function(NotAllowedException $exception, $code)
{
    return Response::json(array(
        'error' => 'Something went wrong (NotAllowedException)'
    ), 401);
});
```

So, in general, you'd want the Exception handler defined first.

Comment: Thank you, I figured out the same behaviour just as you answered here :) Maybe it's helpful for others: as soon as you render a view with View::make, response code is set to 200. To set the code correctly, use Response::view() where you can set the code.